# How to remove the old session variable then set again a new values from that remove old session

Tags: php, laravel

I am still new in Laravel, I am trying to remove the old values of my session.

Here is how I do it.

Controller

```
  public function progress(){

    $category_id = Session::get('category_id'); // [1,2,3]
    $category_type = Session::get('category_type'); //[1,2]

    $new_category_id = array_shift($category_id); //[2,3] new values
    $new_category_type_id = array_shift($category_type); //[2] new values

    session()->forget(['category_id', 'category_type']); //remove session [1,2,3] and store the new one

    session()->put('category_id', $category_id); //[2,3]
    session()->put('category_type', $category_type); //[2] the new values that i want to put in my session
 

  }
```

I just want to remove the first index of my old session, then after I remove it, I will store again the new values of my session. When I tried to call it on my function the new session, the session is empty,  What am I doing wrong in my code?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This works for me `\Session::put('name', 'sta');`

Comment: i already tried that sir, and its not working :(

Comment: Are you sure `$category_id` is not empty? try manually  `session()->put('category_id', [2,3]);`

Comment: when i am trying to use ```session()->put('category_id', $category_id);``` and print again my session, the session is empty sir.

Comment: whenever i am trying to put the new value of the ```category_id and the category_type``` using ```session()->put('category_id', $category_id);``` the session is becoming empty, i dont know why.

Comment: `category_id ` exist & not empty? check with `dd($category_id);`

Comment: @sta i tried your suggestion sir by inserting manually, and its working, but when i tried to use my variable, the session becomes empty :'(

Comment: then `$category_id` is empty, when you trying to insert it on session. I think your session put method is fine, the problem is on your variable, may be its `null`, not `[2,3]`

Comment: and when i try to use new key like this ```session()->put('new_category_id', $category_id);``` it works, but when i try to just reuse my old key, it is becoming empty :( , it means that my $category_id is not empty sir. because when i try to use a new key, i can store it.

Comment: Acoording  to the doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#storing-data set session via a request instance `$request->session()->put('key', 'value');` Via the global helper `session(['key' => 'value']);`